Nginx limit parallel connections
I want to limit the amount of parallel connections to the nginx to 10 while NOT dropping the exessive ones - they should be put in a queue and processed later.
Is that the right configuration for that requirement?
upstream myservice {
    server 127.0.0.1:80;
    server 123.123.123.123:80;
}

set $const 1;
limit_conn_zone $const zone=one:1m;

location / {
    limit_conn one 10;
    proxy_pass  http://myservice;
    proxy_set_header Host myservice;
}


I guess you've mixed up connections and requests and actually you need limit_req_zone/limit_req.

Yes true, I meant requests. Can you provide me an example for that?
